# How to get matrix style data using SQL statement in MySQL using three tables

Tags: mysql, matrix, subquery

I have three tables with the middle table is the many-to-many resulting table (AB). What is the most efficient SQL statement to get:

1 - All records from the two other tables (Table A and Table B) regardless if there are matching data in Table AB
2 - Each record should show true if the two tables are linked (i.e. there is a rercord in the many-many resulting table) or false if it is null

Basically I want to display a matrix table with first column displaying all records from table A, and the first row showing all recrods table B, then the intersecting cells should be ticked if there a matching record in table AB.

If I do not mind parsing the final data set programatically if I have to

Thank you

Comment: The other way around: construct this matrix in your program, not in sql.

Comment: This is going to be my last resort whcih i do not favour. I want to minimise parsing the result in the code as much as possible. Maybe at most a single loop with a toggle to rearrange the data set

Comment: Ok, let me be more clear: it is a terrible idea trying to do this transformation in mysql, since it only changes how you represent the data. Programming tools are a lot more efficient in such transformations.

Comment: I clearly understand but my aim is to make sure i use one db request, get all the data i need and using single loop with toggle i should be able to transform the data

Comment: You can get all data with one query, just not in a matrix format.

Comment: Great, thats what i want but  i am unable to get the data in one query. I basically need a left/right join on table A and B (regardless if there is a match so i can build my headers and the first column) and i want the table AB data as well to show me if there is a match or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT A.id AS "A id", B.id AS "B id", AB.id IS NOT NULL AS "Match"
FROM A
  JOIN B
    LEFT JOIN AB ON A.id = A_id AND B.id = B_id
```

The [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cef63/3/0) also has an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I have not tested it yet, but this will get me one full (either A or B) but not both. I will test and see